# Java\JSON: UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "CefMessagesGenerators" error

Tags: java, json

I have the following Json and corresponding Java classes.

Could you please check it out and advise why do I get this exception?

Is it because I added another

---

```
public class CefMessagesGenerator {

    private String ip;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    //getters and setters    
}


public class CefMessagesGenerators {

    private List<CefMessagesGenerator> cefMessagesGeneratorList = null;

    public CefMessagesGenerators() {
    }

    public CefMessagesGenerators(List<CefMessagesGenerator> cefMessagesGeneratorList) {
        super();
        this.cefMessagesGeneratorList = cefMessagesGeneratorList;
    }

    public List<CefMessagesGenerator> getCefMessagesGeneratorList() {
        return cefMessagesGeneratorList;
    }

    public void setCefMessagesGeneratorList(List<CefMessagesGenerator> cefMessagesGeneratorList) {
        this.cefMessagesGeneratorList = cefMessagesGeneratorList;
    }
}

public class ControllerLab {

    private KubernetesCluster kubernetesCluster;
    private AzureEnvironment azureEnvironment;
    private PortalEnv portalEnv;
    private List<CefMessagesGenerator> cefMessagesGenerators = null;

    //getters and setters

    public List<CefMessagesGenerator> getCefMessagesGenerators() {
        return cefMessagesGenerators;
    }

    public void setCefMessagesGenerators(List<CefMessagesGenerator> cefMessagesGenerators) {
        this.cefMessagesGenerators = cefMessagesGenerators;
    }
}
```

and the (partial) json is:

[image]

(Unfortunately I had to add the json image instead as text here because the system claims "I have the following Json and corresponding Java classes."...)

Comment: Are you parsing json yourself some were? Is there any code for that?

Comment: Note that your property is named `cefMessagesGenerators` while your Json seems to have `CefMessagesGenerators` (starts with a capital C).

Comment: Aside from anything else, the `CefMessagesGenerators` class seems to be redundant.

Comment: @Thomas You are right. But the opposite way!!! I changed the json label to start with small letter and left the class name to begin with a capital letter and it worked (don't understand why...). If you'd like - you can answer the question and I'll accept it!!

Comment: @JonSkeet Why Jon? Because there is only one item there? There will be more in the future...

Comment: @dushkin: Because it's not used. You've got a `List<CefMessagesGenerator>` which contains the list of generators - you never refer to the `CefMessagesGenerators` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already described in the comments the main problem would be that your json contains the property name `CefMessagesGenerators` but the class `ControllerLab` contains the property `cefMessagesGenerators` (note the case difference for the first letter). Thus The parser can't find the property "CefMessagesGenerators".

To solve this there would be a couple of options, depending on which parser you're using:

- Rename the json property to "cefMessagesGenerators" (preferred option)
- Define a non-standard propertyname in your Pojo (e.g. via some annotation like Jackson's `@JsonProperty`)
- Define a custom naming strategy that allows the parser to map `CefMessagesGenerators` to `cefMessagesGenerators`

Note that the first option would be the preferred one for multiple reasons. One of the more important reasons would be that by doing so you wouldn't violate the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) (people would expect the property names to match exactly).

Finally, to quote your comment:

> I changed the json label to start with small letter and left the class name to begin with a capital letter and it worked (don't understand why...)

Note that the class `CefMessagesGenerators` is not relevant here since it is not used by `ControllerLab`. Thus the class name doesn't matter at all.